# How to prevent light flicker in Unity-Engine 2D game with Alpha Blend enabled?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development, light

My lights in my Unity-Engine 2D game keep flickering on certain camera positions. It only started happening after enabling the Overlap Operation "Alpha Blend". I would like to use it as to not have my lights get too bright when multiple are stacked, which is likely to happen in my game.
Why does Alpha Blend cause this and how could I fix/ workaround it?

Here is a video of what is happening:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-NiHZ32lzY

I appreciate and advice! Thank you!

I tried changing the z-position of the lights, but the problem seems to persist.

It only happens when Alpha Blend is the Overlap Operation. On Additive Overlap it doesnt happen.